# El checkbox no realiza la acción que debería

Tags: html, css, checkbox

Se supone que cuando el checkbox está `checked` debería desplegar un menú; intenté cambiar la acción para ver si funcionaba pero nada sirve. Ya sé que con bootstrap lo puedo hacer más fácil pero la idea era desarrollarlo desde cero. También intenté cambiar la sintaxis del checkbox pero ninguna de las dos funcionó.

```html
<nav class="navbar">
      <input id="navToggle" type="checkbox">
      <label for="navToggle" class="navIcon">
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="line"></div>
      </label>
      <ul class="materias">
        <li><a href="index.html">Programa</a></li>
        <li><a href="matematicas.html">Matemáticas</a></li>
        <li><a href="cSociales.html">C. Sociales</a></li>
        
      </ul>
      
    </nav>
```

```css
@media screen and (max-width:750px) {
    .navbar .materias{
        float: none;
        position:fixed;
        z-index: 9px;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 119px;
        bottom: 100%;
        flex-direction: column;
        width:auto;
        height:auto;
        background-color:#ade8f4ec;
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: all .5% ease-in-out;
    }
    .navbar .navIcon{
        display: block;
    }
    #navToggle:checked ~ .navbar .materias{
        bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema lo tenés en el último selector:

```
#navToggle:checked ~ .navbar .materias {
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Estás diciendo un `#navToggle:checked` que tenga un [hermano](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) `.navbar .materias`, pero eso no existe. Como hermano tiene a `.materias` no a `.navbar .materias`.

Debería ser así:

```
#navToggle:checked ~ .materias {
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Éstos son tus elementos y sus jerarquías:

```
.navbar
    #navToggle
    .navIcon
    .materias
```

Como podemos ver, `#navToggle`, `.navIcon` y `.materias` están todos dentro de `.navbar` y al mismo nivel entre sí.

Cuando vos escribís `#navToggle ~ .navbar .materias` le estás diciendo que al mismo nivel que `#navToggle` tiene que haber un `.navbar` y dentro un `.materias`, algo así:

```
.navbar
    #navToggle
    .navbar
        .materias
```

Por eso simplemente lo que tenés que hacer es quitar el `.navbar` y dejar solo `.materias`, porque es ese elemento el que está al mismo nivel que `#navToggle`.

Comment: Que pena pero estoy empezando, si no te molesta me podrías explicar lo de el hermano? Te lo agradecería mucho. Ya hice la corrección y sirvió, muchas gracias.

Comment: @JulianBurbanoFigueredo ahí agregué una explicación, fijate si se termina de entender. Si la respuesta solucionó tu problema, no te olvides de marcarla como aceptada.